# What is an "AddOn" project?

Tags: acumatica

I have an Acumatica instruction document that seems to be from a much older version of Acumatica. In the documentation, it mentions that I need to go to System -> Customization -> Manage -> Customization Projects and select the Visual Studio Drop Down -> Create AddOn Project. Currently I do not see the Visual Studio drop down as mentioned in this document.

Does this option still exist in newer version of Acumatica? If so, how do I access it? If not, does anyone know what type of project I need to create in Visual Studio to manually do what this option did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An Add-On project is a visual studio solution containing your Acumatica extension in the form of a dynamically linked library. You can access it by opening the Project Editor for customizations and going to the Extension Library menu.

[image: VS Extension]
Updated Acumatica training documents are available at the following URL:
http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/courses/