# References inside a customization opened in Visual Studio

Tags: acumatica

I am working inside Visual Studio 2017, I have 2 DAC's and 1 graph file all in App_Runtimecode, is there a build or other setting that I that I have to set so that the Graph can "find" the DAC's for the autocomplete?

[image: Open Files]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files in App_RuntimeCode are compiled dynamically on demand by IIS. IntelliSense works on statically compiled code and therefore can't parse dynamic code. To have complete IntelliSense support requires creating an [Extension Library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42697599/7376238) instead of a Runtime customization project.

Comment: Much appreciated